# Automatically moving a bicycle to the goal without using arrow keys or any input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am new to game development and working on a game development project where I want to move an object automatically to the goal without any input. Can anyone tell me how to resolve the issue I am facing. Here's what the code looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Bike_controller : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Wheel colliders")]
    public WheelCollider frontWheelCollider;
    public WheelCollider backWheelCollider;

    [Header("Wheel Transform")]
    public Transform frontWheelTransform;
    public Transform backWheelTransform;

    [Header("Handle Transform")]
    public Transform cycleHandle;

    [Header("Bike Power")]
    public float accelerationForce = 200f;
    public float breakingForce = 3000f;
    private float presentBreakForce = 0f;
    private float presentAcceleration = 0f;

    [Header("Bike steering")]
    public float steeringAngle = 35f;
    private float presentTurnAngle = 0f;
    
    private void Update()
    {
        MoveBike();
        SteerBike();
    }

    private void MoveBike()
    {
        backWheelCollider.motorTorque = presentAcceleration;
        presentAcceleration = accelerationForce * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    }

    private void SteerBike()
    {
        presentTurnAngle = steeringAngle * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        frontWheelCollider.steerAngle = presentTurnAngle;
        movewheels(frontWheelCollider, frontWheelTransform);
        movewheels(backWheelCollider, backWheelTransform);
    }

    private void movewheels(WheelCollider WC, Transform WT)
    {
        Vector3 position;
        Quaternion rotation;
        WC.GetWorldPose(out position, out rotation);
    }

}
```

Instead of using both "Input.GetAxis("Vertical")" and "Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")", I want to use a method for automatically moving an object to the goal without any input.

Comment: well you havent mentioned how it would know where to go, but have you considered using unity timeline?

Comment: Its not clear what issue you are trying to resolve.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/). We will not write code to specification for you here. Plagiarism is a serious academic offense; aside from that, we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and analyze the task, identify the logical steps to solve the problem, and figure out *where you are actually stuck*. Make sure to check if the issue is already addressed in another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure if this is the answer you are looking for, but you should be using:

```
presentAcceleration = accelerationForce * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime;
```

as using [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) creates a *frame rate independence* that runs more or less the same on every device. **In the event that you wish to move an object without input**, you may simply remove `Input.GetAxis("Vertical")` and adjust the variable `accelerationForce` until the moment is what you want.

Alternatively, you could use [`Vector3.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) to adjust the position of your `GameObject`'s `transform` over time within a [`Coroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) or within the `Update()` function (again use `Time.deltaTime` as a best practice).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use UnityEngine.AI

First, add a NavMeshAgent component to your bicycle and add a new script to it and add the following code in Start method.

```
myNavMeshAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
myNavMeshAgent.SetDestination(yourDestination.transform.position);
```

Remember to add NavMeshSurface component to your floor/ground and bake it by pressing bake button. Before baking make the ground and other obstacles static.

[Read more here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshAgent.SetDestination.html)

If your path is not very complicated you can also use timeline to create an animation for the bicycle.